# Swift Math Answering 0

Tags: swift, math, percentage

I am trying to calculate a percentage of how many spaces are available in green street. When I do the calculation (greenStreetSpaces / greenStreetTotalSpaces) * 100 the returned answer is 0.

Here is my code

```
var greenStreetSpaces = json["carparkData"]["Jersey"]["carpark"][0]["spaces"].intValue
            print(greenStreetSpaces)
            var greenStreetTotalSpaces = 608
            print(greenStreetTotalSpaces)

            let greenStreetPercent = (greenStreetSpaces / greenStreetTotalSpaces) * 100
            print(greenStreetPercent)
```

and the console from me printing the results.

[The snippet of relevant results on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjNAm.png)

Comment: if you expect Int result, then let greenStreetPercent = (100 * greenStreetSpaces / greenStreetTotalSpaces) is probably what you are looking for ...., othewise use floating point calculation.

Comment: In many programming languages (including Swift), dividing two integers results in an integer and truncates the result. A Google search for "division gives zero" shows you lots of similar questions with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This operator "/" applied to 2 integers returns the integer part of the division

Example

```
let greenStreetSpaces = 10
let greenStreetTotalSpaces = 15

greenStreetSpaces / greenStreetTotalSpaces // 0
```

To solve the problem you should divide `Doubles`

```
(Double(greenStreetSpaces) / Double(greenStreetTotalSpaces)) * 100 // 66.66666666666666
```